# sql server AS error expecting conversation

Tags: sql-server

I have this CASE syntax:

```
CASE WHEN (dbo.Futuredial_Validation.[Error Code]='1')
THEN (dbo.Futuredial_Validation.LocalTime AS att.Date_cleared) END 
AS att.Date_cleared
```

I'm having the error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Can someone tell me if I can use AS inside the case structure like this?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `alias` name inside `case` statement

```
CASE WHEN dbo.Futuredial_Validation.[Error Code]='1' THEN 
       dbo.Futuredial_Validation.LocalTime END AS [att.Date_cleared]
```

Also add parenthesis when it is really needed. Adding unwanted parenthesis makes the query and conditions clumsy

Another improvement can be done by using alias names to your table `Futuredial_Validation F`

Query will be like

```
Select CASE WHEN F.[Error Code]='1' THEN F.LocalTime END AS [att.Date_cleared]
From dbo.Futuredial_Validation F
```

As mentioned in comments, it is better to avoid `.` in alias name else you have to use square brackets to escape it.

Comment: OP - One addition here is that you a strange name for the alias. Why use att.? That will force you to add [] around the alias. so it would be [att.Date_cleared]. Removing that prefix would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @SeanLange - Didn't notice that. Thanks

Comment: No problem @Prdp. I am thinking perhaps the OP is confused and that is an existing table alias already which of course will generate and even more bizarre error. :)

Comment: Thank you I kind of followed your suggestions and the case problem is solved now I have another one!!

Comment: @YalinaLopez - Then ask a new question. If this answer helped you then mark it as answer by selecting the tick mark to the left of this answer